# Android SectionIndexer Does not Show Alphabetic Preview beyond "A"

Tags: android

I have implemented the SectionIndexer on my Adapter and the FastScroll as well. The fast scroll appears, but the alphabetic indexer is always "A" as I scroll

The list is about 1000 items long.

Here's my implementation of the SectionIndexer.

```
    @Override
    public int getPositionForSection(int section) {
        return alphaIndexer.getPositionForSection(section);
    }

    @Override
    public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
        return alphaIndexer.getSectionForPosition(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Object[] getSections() {
        return alphaIndexer.getSections();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a bug in my code, wrong field being used.

Comment: what was the mistake? Please post the solution.